# C++ Variadic templates

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Здравствуйте есть следующий класс, со следующей реализацией:

```
template<typename Type>
class List : public Memory::INonCopyable
{
    struct Node
    {
        Type value;
        Node* next;
        Node* prev;
    };
public:
    explicit List(std::uint8_t countVirtualPages = 1) noexcept
        : mAllocator(countVirtualPages, sizeof(Node)) {}
    template<typename... Arguments>
    void emplaceFront(Arguments&&... arguments) noexcept;
    ...
private:
    std::size_t mSize = 0;
    Node* mHead = nullptr;
    Node* mTail = nullptr;
    Memory::Allocators::PoolAllocator mAllocator;
};

template<typename Type>
template<typename... Arguments>
void List<Type>::emplaceFront(Arguments&&... arguments) noexcept 
{
    void* memoryForNode = mAllocator.allocate(sizeof(Node));
    Node* newNode = new (memoryForNode) Node((std::forward<Arguments>(arguments)...), mHead, nullptr);
    if (isEmpty()) 
    {
        mHead = mTail = newNode;
    }
    else 
    {
        mHead->prev = newNode;
        mHead = newNode;
    }
}
```

При использовании функции emplaceFront получаю следующие ошибки:

```
Error   C2760   syntax error: unexpected token '...', expected ')'  
Error   C3520   'arguments': parameter pack must be expanded in this context
Error   C2059   syntax error: '...'
```

Как можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: Скобочки поменяйте на фигурные `Node{{std::forward<Arguments>(arguments)...}, mHead, nullptr}`

Comment: @nick_n_a, думаю тут и дураку понятно в каком месте она возникла, и без нажатия кнопочки, вопрос был явно задан как устранить ошибку(так как мало опыта с varidaic templates), а не где ее найти, и стандарт 17 используется, Поэтому не стоит так выставлять других дураками...

Comment: @Croessmah, спасибо, ошибка и правда была в скобках...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Вашем случае достаточно поменять скобочки на фигурные:

```
Node{{std::forward<Arguments>(arguments)...}, mHead, nullptr}
```

Разберем на более простом примере что же у Вас не так.

```
#include <utility>

template<typename T>
struct Node
{
    T value;
    void * unused;
};


template<typename T, typename ... Args>
void f(Args && ... args)
{
    delete new Node<T>((std::forward<Args>(args)...), nullptr);
}

struct First
{
    First(int, int, int) {}
    int m1;
    int m2;
    int m3;
};

int main()
{
    f<First>(1, 2, 3);
}
```

При передаче в функцию `f<First>` трех параметров получается примерно следующий код создания объекта `Node<First>`:

```
//int_* - параметры функции после распаковки пакета параметров
//std::forward опущен, т.к. в данном случае он не столь важен и не играет роли.
Node<First>((int_1, int_2, int_3), nullptr);
```

синтаксис с круглыми скобками при создании объекта приводит к вызову конструктора с заданным набором параметров, но в `Node` нет конструктора с параметрами.
В то же время `Node` является агрегатом и объекты этого типа можно инициализировать с помощью "списочной инициализации":

```
Node<First>{(int_1, int_2, int_3), nullptr};
```

Далее посмотрим на скобки с параметрами `int_*`, которые должны были бы инициализировать подъобъект `First`. В данном случае это не список параметров, а всего лишь скобки с операторами "запятая" и операндами оного. Для создания объекта нужно указать тип создаваемого объекта, например, так:

```
Node<T>{T(int_1, int_2, int_3), nullptr};
```

Это приведет к вызову конструктора типа `T` с тремя параметрами.
Но, если в нашем примере у типа `First` убрать конструктор, то код снова откажется компилироваться, т.к. отсутствует подходящий конструктор. Однако, объект типа `First` возможно инициализировать с помощью всё той же списочной инициализации, т.е. так:

```
Node<T>{{int_1, int_2, int_3}, nullptr};
```

Вернем назад `std::forward` с пакетом параметров. Получим такой шаблон:

```
template<typename T, typename ... Args>
void f(Args && ... args)
{
    delete new Node<T>{{std::forward<Args>(args)...}, nullptr};
}
```

То есть теперь данный код может работать не только с типами, имеющими необходимые конструкторы, но и с типами, которые можно инициализировать с помощью `list-initialization`.